# creating set from input

Tags: java, set

I want to create a set of elements from the given input.
(i.e. i/p : 5 5 4 4 4 3 3 3 3 2 2 2 1 1 1 ,then o/p : 5 4 3 2 1)

I have a logic: create an array and store the elements in it.successively read elements and write a loop which will assign boolean false if two elements (the current chosen element and an element from the array whose index is less than that of the current element) are not the same. After the loop has executed for an element , all the boolean values stored are passed through bitwise OR operation and if the overall value is false , then the current element is pushed to an array that stores the set and the next element is the given sequence is chosen and same operation is performed.

I haven't yet written the code for this. So, is this algo. right? Also, do you know a better algo. to find a set?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You never need to use arrays for this sort of thing. Learn about `List`s and `Set`s and use those instead.

```
Set<Integer> set = new LinkedHashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(5, 5, 4, 4, 3, 2, 4, 3, 1));
System.out.println(set);    // prints [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Comment: I've read it carefully, and it is correct, yes. The only thing I would add is that you should store the results of the bitwise OR operations in a single `boolean` array, so that you can count the number of times `false` appears, so you know how long the final `int` array should be.